# Indexing Groups of Data

Tags: excel, indexing

I have 10,000+ row of values which need to be indexed with a numerical value which increases by 1 every 56 rows - for example:

```
Rows    Index Value
1-56         1
57-112       2
113-168      3
169-224      4
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!  :-)

Comment: Which row does the data start on? #2 perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If your data starts in `Row #2` like your example implies, then try this formula in `Row #2` the column where you want your "index number":

```
=INT((ROW()-1)/56)+1
```

The `1` in the middle is "how many rows to skip at the top", and the `56` is obviously the size of each group.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**`ROW` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d)
- Office Support : [**`INT` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/int-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef)